# running a java file in python using os.system()

Tags: java, python, os.system

I'm trying to run the following code in pycharm using python 3.7

```
os.system("java ToPython")
```

however I get the following error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class ToPython
```

I tried executing the same java file from terminal:

```
javac ToPython.java
java topython
```

and it works perfectly file

note: all the files exist in the same folder

Comment: The current working directory may be different though. Try to call "os.chdir" before "os.system" or try absolute paths.

Comment: Thank you! I changed the working directory using os.chdir() and it worked