# Run java main class in command line/batch file/python script

Tags: python, java

I have a java class which is to be made into a tool so that I can give the input to the class as parameters and then produce the output in the command line, I have written the code in IntelliJ and want the code to be portable so that it can be used instantly by the click of a button. I have little experience in creating a bat file or python script.

```
package ase.ATool;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class AnaliT {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = null;
        File dir = new File(args[0]);
        File[] directoryListing = dir.listFiles();

        StringBuffer componentString = new StringBuffer(100);
        if (directoryListing != null) {
            for (File child : directoryListing) {
                float complexity = 0, noOfMethods = 0;
                System.out.println(child.getPath() + " ");
                String currentLine;
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(child.getPath()));
                    System.out.println(bufferedReader);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

I want to convert the above code in to a tool so i can invoke this main function from the command line, batch file or python file.

Comment: You can a compile the java file using "javac" and then run it with "java". Are you looking to do something else here ?

Comment: Or do you mean you want to create a python script to run this ? Please a little more information :)

Comment: yup a python script would be nice, so that a simple run of the script with arguments completes the work

Comment: Python script to run Java? Import `os`, then in the same folder run something like `os.system("javac AnaliT.java")` then `os.system("java Anali")`. With the command line just go to the same folder and run `javac AnaliT.java` and then `java AnaliT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compile and run the java file from python by checking out the *subprocess* module:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

You can also run java code using the system module: [running a java file in python using os.system()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60713070/running-a-java-file-in-python-using-os-system)

If you want to invoke Java code from python, take a look here:
[Calling Java from Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652554/calling-java-from-python)
Here it is recommended you use [Py4J](http://py4j.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Here you can find an example of running a Java Class from a .bat file: [How to run java application by .bat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8938944/how-to-run-java-application-by-bat-file)

As mentioned in a comment you can also compile the file with java using `java target.java` and then run it with `java target` in the same directory

I hope by showing you some of these resources you can guide yourself towards more specific help.